# How can insert loop for check each value in array [mongoDB,Node.js]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I want to check my input with DB. If input == Data in collection then go to next page

I try success but it only check first value in array.

This code is create data to DB [Success]

```
app.post('/register',function(req,res){
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;

  let dbo = db.db("project");
  let myobj = { Email: req.body.email, Password: req.body.psw } ;

  dbo.collection("Register").insertOne(myobj, function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(" document inserted");
    db.close();
  });
});
    res.render('whatsub');
});
```

This code is my problem to insert for loop

```
app.post('/index',function(req,res){

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("project");

  dbo.collection("Register").findOne({}, function(err, result) {

    if (result.Email == req.body.email && result.Password == req.body.psw) {
      console.log("Correct go next page");
    }
    else{
      console.log("Wrong email/password");
    }
    db.close();
  });
 });
 });
```

Can I use a forEach to check all data in my collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not good practice to select all records from Mongo and then compare with your userName and password.

your code is selecting the first **one record** in mongo as long as you call `findOne` so it doesn't even make any loops as it returns only one record (the first one in the db)

But instead, It is better to do something like the following, select from mongo where `userName` equals the `passed userName` then compare the `password` you sent in the request with the one stored in the DB.

```
//select from mongo collection where email equals the one being passed in req's body [make sure you spell names correctly]
dbo.collection("Register").findOne({email:  req.body.email} , function(err, result) {
  //make sure result is not null, compare Password stored in mongo with the one passed in req's body 
  if (result && result.Password == req.body.psw) {
      console.log("Correct go next page");
    }
    else{
      console.log("Wrong email/password");
    }

});
```

Comment: sry but It not working . Output is TypeError: Cannot read property 'Password' of null

Comment: use "Email" instead of "email", I don't how you store this in mongo, so plz open mongo and make sure you write the correct `field name` findOne({fielName: value})` . ..  if result is null that user is not there in the DB

Comment: Thx, It working if correct Email and wrong/correct  password !! but when I input Email incorrect output is : TypeError: Cannot read property 'Password' of null
/// I'm sorry for wasting your time